# How does queue.js work?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, queue

I've been trying to understand how [Mike Bostock's queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue/blob/master/queue.js) works, but I can't see how it manages to work.  The part I don't understand is how the code manages to continue executing callbacks. In particular, I am unsure about the `pop()` method (line 45).  From my understanding, the method takes the next unprocessed, deferred function; appends a callback that (potentially) starts the next deferred function in the queue and executes when the immediately popped function finishes; then finally executes said function.  My question is: what code executes this callback?

Comment: That's some very poorly-commented code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's a very short and concise code. The variable names are descriptive and their function is commented. I don't see a reason to over-comment it...

Comment: @Bergi: I'm only asking for, like, one or two. Descriptions of what each function does. The OP's question demonstrates the need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each deferred function does not actually return anything -- they are expected to execute their final argument as a callback.  For example, this will not work

```
var foo = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
  return i;
}
var finished = function(error, results) {
  console.log(results);
}

queue(2)
  .defer(foo, 1)
  .defer(foo, 2)
  .defer(foo, 3)
  .defer(foo, 4)
  .awaitAll(finished);  // only prints "1" and "2", since foo() doesn't execute callbacks
```

However, if we modify `foo` to take a callback,

```
var foo = function(i, callback) {
  console.log(i);
  callback(null, i);  // first argument is error reason, second is result
}
```

Then it will, as executing the callback causes `queue` to continue.

Comment: Nice example, really helped me

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the code correctly, `queue.await()` and `queue.awaitall()` put the callback in the `await` instance variable, and then this is executed by `notify()`.