# Nested JSON loadings in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the proper way to do nested loading of JSON files in D3.js. This is the code im trying to use. The problem im having is that d.dataset.toString() return the error Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined.

main.json

```
[
    {
        "name" : "A-Module",
        "file" : "a.json"
    },
    {
        "name" : "B-Module",
        "file" : "b.json"
    }
]
```

a.json

```
[
    {
        "owner" : "A-Module",
        "dataset" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
]
```

b.json

```
[
    {

        "owner" : "B-Module",
        "dataset" : [7,8,9,10]
    }
]
```

---

```
    var width = 500,
        height = 500,
        svg;

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height",height);

    d3.json("main.json", function(metrics){

        for (var i=0; i<metrics.length; i++){
            var path = metrics[i].file;
            d3.json(path,function(data){
                for(var j=0; j<metrics.length;j++){
                    var owner = data.owner;
                    var metricName = metrics[j].name;

                    if (owner === metricName){
                        metrics[j].dataset = data.dataset;
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(metrics)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d,i){
            return d.dataset.toString();
        });
    });
```

--- Updated non working example with Queue.js, the problem I now have is that "owner" is undefined.

```
    var width = 500,
        height = 500,
        svg;

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height",height);

    d3.json("main.json", function(metrics){
        var tasks = [],
            q = queue(1),
            path;
        for (var i=0; i<metrics.length; i++){
            path = metrics[i].file;
            tasks[i] = function(callback) {
                d3.json(path,function(data){
                    for(var j=0; j<metrics.length;j++){
                        var owner = data.owner;
                        var metricName = metrics[j].name;
                        console.log("1",owner,"2", metricName)
                        if (owner === metricName){
                            metrics[j].dataset = data.dataset;
                            callback(null,data);
                            console.log("THIS SHOULD NEVER PRINT");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                });
            };
        }
        tasks.forEach(function(t) { q.defer(t); });
        q.awaitAll(function(error, results) { 
            svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(metrics)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d,i){
                return d.dataset.toString();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `d3.json` is asynchronous. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455194/how-to-store-a-json-object-loaded-from-a-file) may help.

Comment: And how do I possible do it if I have one main JSON file which contains 10 difference companies, it stores information about name, adress etc, for each of these 10companies I want to create a g element and fill that g element with name and adress. AND then for each company there exists also a data_companyA.json file containing data I want to use to draw a line graph that should be put in the corresponding company's g element. Could you plz draw up some pseudo code showing how I can do this since I'm totally lost for days now and it sucks :(

Comment: Well you would need nested JSON callbacks or use something like [queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue).

Comment: Still cant get it to work but have rewritten the question so that it is now obv what im trying to do and how im doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: It does look like you would want to use queue. Add all the files you need to retrieve and handle the data in the callback.

Comment: Yes it looks like that is what im looking for. However I have problems understanding what I am supposed to save in "tasks", how should the functions look like in this case that I will be saving in tasks? I have added updated code in my question.

Comment: It might be easier to use the first form, i.e. `q.defer(d3.json, url)` for each task and then handle all the data in the `awaitAll` callback.

Comment: But I do not know before hand how many files I am to load? So this is why I cant use the first form.

Comment: I have updated the question again with new code, this time it runs but owner gets no value.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally got it working. Look at the code below for a working example and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008868/how-does-queue-js-work) for more details.

```
        var width = 500,
            height = 500,
            svg;

        svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height",height);

        d3.json("main.json", function(metrics){
            var tasks = [],
                q = queue(),
                paths = [];
            for (var i=0; i<metrics.length; i++){
                paths[i] = metrics[i].file;
            }
            paths.forEach(function(fileName){

                q.defer(function(callback) {
                    d3.json(fileName,function(data){ callback(null, data) });
                });
            });

            q.awaitAll(restOfCode)

            function restOfCode(err, results){
                //Add files into one big file and all the rest of my data bindings
                for(var j=0; j<results.length;j++){
                    for(var k=0; k<metrics.length;k++){
                        var owner = results[j][0].owner ;
                        var metricName = metrics[k].name;
                        if (owner === metricName){
                            metrics[k].dataset = results[j][0].dataset;
                        }
                    }
                }
                svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(metrics)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .append("text")
                .text(function(d,i){
                    return d.dataset.toString();
                });
            }
        })
```